# Can I add nodes running on my machine to AWS EKS cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Well, I read the user guide of AWS EKS service. I created a managed node group for the EKS cluster successfully.

I don't know how to add the nodes running on my machine to the EKS cluster. I don't know whether EKS support. I didn't find any clue in its document. I read the 'self-managed node group' chapter, which supports add a self-managed EC2 instances and auto-scaling group to the EKS cluster rather than a private node running on other cloud instance like azure, google cloud or my machine.

Does EKS support? How to do that if supports?

Comment: thats not possible as per I know.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. It is (implicitly) called out in [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html). All worker nodes need to be deployed in the same VPC where you deployed the control plane (not necessarily the same subnets though). EKS Anywhere (to be launched later this year) will allow you to deploy a complete EKS cluster (control plane + workers) outside of an AWS region (but it won't allow running the control plane in AWS and workers locally).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, EKS service doesn't support adding self nodes to the cluster. But the 'EKS Anywhere' service does, which has not been online yet, but soon.